# subs() for large number of variables

Tags: python, sympy

I am working on optimization, and I want to code a functions where I can sub() larger number of variables.
for this, I generated a m functions with n variables. For example, let say 3 functions and 2 variables.

```
num_var=2
x=symbols('x0:num_var')
```

I generated this functions:

```
f=[5*x0 + 4*x1 + 6, -4*x0 - 5*x1 - 6, -8*x0 - 10]
```

and I have a point like:

```
point=[-2.8,1.74]
```

If I want to sub() in each function, what is the fastest way to do this?

```
f[0].subs([(x[0],point[0]),(x[1],point[1])])
```

(this will give evaluation of first function in point)
And I get three function evaluations in list:

```
fun_eval=[some number,some number, ... (in size of number of functions)]
```

The question is how can I write a code to do evaluations for larger number of variables in large number of functions?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x0, x1 = x = symbols('x:2')
>>> f = [5*x0+4*x1+6, -4*x0-5*x1-6, -8*x0-10]
>>> point = (-2.8, 1.74)
>>> [fi.subs(zip(x, point)) for fi in f]
[-1.04000000000000, -3.50000000000000, 12.4000000000000]
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#lambdify. If you want to efficiently evaluate a function at a large number of points, you should use `lambdify`.

```
>>> func = lambdify(x, f)
>>> func(*point)
[-1.04, -3.5, 12.399999999999999]
```

By default, it uses subs, but if you have `numpy` installed, you can use it for much faster evaluation, by passing `module="numpy"` to `lambdify`.

By the way, your `symbols('x0:num_var')` does not actually use the `num_var` variable. You need to use `symbols('x0:%d' % num_var)`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I switched from sympy to numpy. I find it much more efficient. Because all of my functions right now are linear, I am using numpy.array().